# Who gave right hand thumb rule for circular loop of current conducting wire?

Tags: electromagnetism

To find magnetic field due to current conducting **straight wire** we have **Maxwell's Right hand thumb rule**, Which says ***"Put your right hand thumb in the direction of current then curled fingers shows the direction of field"*** I can see that this can be used for a current conducting loop but there is another version for a loop.

To find magnetic field due to a current conducting **loop** is given by **another right hand thumb rule.** The rule says ***"curl your fingers of right hand along the direction of current then thumb gives the direction of field"***

My question is that who gave the second rule. Is it given by Maxwell himself or someone else? Is it modified version of first stated rule? Who should I credit for the second rule?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_right-hand_rule).

Answer (score 2):

Right-hand rule was invented for use in electromagnetism by British physicist John Ambrose Fleming in the late 19th century.

Comment: But my question is that who gave alternative form of Maxwell's Right hand rule for current and magnetic field only?

Comment: Maxwell gave the rule for B and I only. While Fleming gave the rule for FBI.